# SQLSRV Query Returning Output Parameter As Strange Text

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlsrv

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 which first checks if data exists, if it does then it sets the Output parameter `@Return` to 1 and runs a select query and if not, sets `@Return` to 0 and returns a different select query.

When testing this stored procedure to ensure the data is accurate it is perfect and returns the data I am expecting. The problem lies on the PHP side when trying to read the output parameter it is showing `��t_rrr` when it should be showing a 1 or 0. I believe the problem may be in the Predefined Constant in the sqlsrv_query but i cannot seem to get it working. Here is my code:

**PHP:**

```php
if(isset($_GET['accno'])) {

$search = $_GET['accno'];

$return = "";

$tsql_callSP = "EXEC Intranet.CustomerSearch @Search=?, @Return=?";
$params = array( 
    array($search, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array($return, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING(SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR),SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_INT),
    );

/* Execute the query. */
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql_callSP, $params);
if( $stmt === false )
{
    echo "EXEC Intranet.CustomerSearch Failed\n";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

while($res = sqlsrv_next_result($stmt))
{
    // make sure all result sets are stepped through, 
    // since the output params may not be set until this happens
}

echo $return;

if($return == 0) { ?>

   //1st Result Set
   while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)) {
   }

<?php } elseif($return == 1) { // End if Return 0 ?>

   //2nd Result Set
   while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)) {
   }

<?php } // End if Return 1 ?>
```

**SQL Stored Procedure:**

```sql
USE [Intranet]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [Intranet].[CustomerSearch]
    @Search nvarchar(10)
    ,@Return int output
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS
        (
            SELECT KeyCode
            FROM Autopart.dbo.Customer
            WHERE KeyCode = @Search
        )
    BEGIN

        SELECT
            Customer.KeyCode
            ,Customer.X13
            ,Customer.Name
            ,Customer.Addra
            ,Customer.Addrb
            ,Customer.Addrc
            ,Customer.Addrd
            ,Customer.Addre
            ,Customer.PCode
            ,Customer.CTitle
            ,Customer.Climit
            ,Customer.Ptype
            ,Customer.Stel
            ,Customer.SCont
            ,Customer.ACont
            ,Customer.XString5
            ,Customer.Locked
            ,Customer.Email
            ,Customer.StopStatus
            ,CusNotes.Comment
        FROM
            Autopart.dbo.Customer
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Autopart.dbo.CusNotes ON Autopart.dbo.Customer.KeyCode = Autopart.dbo.CusNotes.Account
        WHERE
            (Customer.KeyCode = @Search)
            AND (CusNotes.Seqno = 1 OR CusNotes.Seqno IS NULL)

        SET @Return = 1

    END ELSE BEGIN

        SELECT TOP 100
            KeyCode
            ,Name
            ,PCode
            ,Addra
            ,Addrb
            ,Addrc
        FROM
            AUTOPART.dbo.Customer
        WHERE
            (KeyCode LIKE '%'+@Search+'%'
            OR Name LIKE '%'+@Search+'%'
            OR PCode LIKE '%'+@Search+'%')

        SET @Return = 0

    END
END
```

I have tried changing the PHP and SQL types around but can't get the desired result. What is strange is if I create a stored procedure that is an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement the `OUTPUT` returns correctly.

**EDIT:**

SQL Server Stored Procedure Collation is Latin1_General_CI_AS

Comment: Try: `$return = 0;` instead of `$return = "";` and `SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT` instead of `SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT` and `SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_INT(SQLSRV_ENC_BINARY)` instead of  `SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING`.

Comment: Change the `$return` variable as suggested, changed the param type to `SQLRV_PARAM_INOUT` and the PHPTYPE to `array($return, SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_INT,SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_INT),` Now i am always returning a 0 regardless of query (No silly characters though) and `mb_detect_encoding` detects as ASCII

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I happened to have SQL Server and PHP installed on my VirtualBox, so I played around.

Few things:

- Init parameters with the value of a proper type.
- Use `&` when passing parameters.
- Read all results that the stored procedure returns using [`sqlsrv_next_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-next-result.php). This advice is taken from [`sqlsrv_prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php) in the example at the bottom.

Here is the code:

```php
$search = "qweryt";
$return = 123;

$tsql_callSP = "EXEC Intranet.CustomerSearch @Search=?, @Return=?";
$params = array( 
    array(&$search, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array(&$return, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT),
    );

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql_callSP, $params);
if ($stmt === false)
{
    echo "EXEC Intranet.CustomerSearch Failed\n";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
else
{
    while($res = sqlsrv_next_result($stmt))
    {
        // make sure all result sets are stepped through, 
        // since the output params may not be set until this happens
    }
}

echo $return;
```

Verified with PHP 5.4.28, SQL Server Express 2014, Microsoft driver for PHP SQLSRV 3.2

When you have a stored procedure that does only `INSERT` or `UPDATE`, i.e. doesn't return result of `SELECT`, then `sqlsrv_next_result` happen to be not needed to get values of the `output` parameters. If there is `SELECT` together with output parameters, it effectively means that procedure returns several result sets and you need to read all of them.

Actually, here is a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25412675/php-get-return-value-from-mssql-stored-procedure).

### Edit

If I understood you correctly, you want to retrieve the value of the `OUTPUT` parameter first. Then you want to retrieve the result of the `SELECT` statement.

As far as I understand, it is not possible. SQL Server returns result of `SELECT` statement in the first result set, which you can read using [`sqlsrv_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php). Then you move to the second result set using [`sqlsrv_next_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-next-result.php). At this moment the value of the `OUTPUT` parameter is transferred to your PHP variable, because SQL Server sends the values of `OUTPUT` parameters in the last result set. After you call `sqlsrv_next_result` the first result set is no longer available when you do `sqlsrv_fetch_array`.

By the way, when you said

> What is strange is if I create a stored procedure that is an INSERT or
>   UPDATE statement the OUTPUT returns correctly.

, it makes perfect sense. When stored procedure has no `SELECT` statements and it has `SET NOCOUNT ON;`, then the only result set that is returned is for `OUTPUT` parameters, so your PHP variable is assigned with correct value without explicit calls to `sqlsrv_next_result`.

So, you have at least two options.

1) Read the full result of `SELECT` into a temporary array using `sqlsrv_fetch_array`. Then use `sqlsrv_next_result` to get the value of the `OUTPUT` parameter. Then process result of the first `SELECT` saved in your array based on the received value of the `OUTPUT` parameter.

2) Do not use `OUTPUT` parameter at all. With such parameter(s) SQL Server returns multiple result sets implicitly. Since you have multiple result sets any way, return two result sets explicitly. In your stored procedure at first do `SELECT` that returns just one row with one number, then your main `SELECT`:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [Intranet].[CustomerSearch]
    @Search nvarchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS
        (
            SELECT KeyCode
            FROM Autopart.dbo.Customer
            WHERE KeyCode = @Search
        )
    BEGIN
        SELECT CAST(1 AS int) AS ReturnCode;

        SELECT
            Customer.KeyCode
            ,Customer.X13
            ,Customer.Name
            ,Customer.Addra
            ,Customer.Addrb
            ,Customer.Addrc
            ,Customer.Addrd
            ,Customer.Addre
            ,Customer.PCode
            ,Customer.CTitle
            ,Customer.Climit
            ,Customer.Ptype
            ,Customer.Stel
            ,Customer.SCont
            ,Customer.ACont
            ,Customer.XString5
            ,Customer.Locked
            ,Customer.Email
            ,Customer.StopStatus
            ,CusNotes.Comment
        FROM
            Autopart.dbo.Customer
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Autopart.dbo.CusNotes ON Autopart.dbo.Customer.KeyCode = Autopart.dbo.CusNotes.Account
        WHERE
            (Customer.KeyCode = @Search)
            AND (CusNotes.Seqno = 1 OR CusNotes.Seqno IS NULL)
        ;

    END ELSE BEGIN

        SELECT CAST(0 AS int) AS ReturnCode;

        SELECT TOP 100
            KeyCode
            ,Name
            ,PCode
            ,Addra
            ,Addrb
            ,Addrc
        FROM
            AUTOPART.dbo.Customer
        WHERE
            KeyCode LIKE '%'+@Search+'%'
            OR Name LIKE '%'+@Search+'%'
            OR PCode LIKE '%'+@Search+'%'
        ;
    END
END
```

In PHP code call `sqlsrv_fetch_array` first time to read `ReturnCode`. Then call `sqlsrv_next_result` to switch to the second result set. Then call `sqlsrv_fetch_array` to read result of the main `SELECT`.

```php
$search = "qweryt";

$tsql_callSP = "EXEC Intranet.CustomerSearch @ParamSearch=?";
$params = array
    (
    array(&$search, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)
    );

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql_callSP, $params);
if( $stmt === false )
{
    echo "EXEC Failed\n";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

echo "First result set:\n";
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt))
{
    var_dump($row);
}

echo "Next result:\n";
$next_res = sqlsrv_next_result($stmt);
var_dump($next_res);

echo "Second result set:\n";
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt))
{
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your research and help, the `$return` tag is now returned correctly as 1 or 0 as expected. I have noticed i forgot to mention something important which i have added to my question, once the return check comes back it will run `while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)) {` depending on return result

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. Are you receiving correct results now or there is still some problem?

Comment: Sorry, i am receiving the correct result for `$return` however no data from my select statements

Comment: I edited the answer and added more details and options.

Comment: Vladamir! Thank you, this works perfectly and is exactly what I was trying to achieve. I appreciate your time, effort and research. A well deserved bounty. Just one last thing, is there a reason for the `&` before a parameter out of interest?

Comment: You are welcome. `sqlsrv_prepare` returned a warning without `&`, so I thought it should be used in simple `sqlsrv_query` as well.

Comment: I tried with and without and both work fine with `sqlsrv_query` by the looks of things, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a character encoding problem with PHP output. Try using

```html
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

or

```html
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
```

Also, you can check [this nice article.](https://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2011/04/23/how-to-avoid-character-encoding-problems-in-php/)

Comment: I have tried both of these headers as you suggest and the characters change as follows. UTF-8 - 0+��+. ISO-8859-1 - 0ÄðÝÄ. I also tried changing the PHPTYPE to SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_INT

Comment: The stored procedure collation is: Latin1_General_CI_AS if that makes any difference?

Comment: When running `echo mb_detect_encoding($return);` the value echoed is UTF-8