# Use of undefined constant SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR - assumed 'SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR

Tags: php, apache, sqlsrv

I can't get to execute a sp with output parameters with SQL Server 2014, PHP 7 and Apache 2.4.17.

This is the PHP:

```
$nombreUsuario = "DrBrahim";
$contraseña = "123456";
$resultado = "dummie";
$datosBienvenida = "dummie";

$sql = "{CALL LOGINv2 (?, ?, ?, ?)}";
$params = array(
    array($nombreUsuario, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array($contraseña, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
    array(&$resultado, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT, null, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR),
    array(&$datosBienvenida, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT, null, SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR),
);
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);

if($stmt === false){
    echo 'No se pudo ejecutar la consulta:<br>';
    var_dump(sqlsrv_errors());

    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
else{
    sqlsrv_next_result($stmt);
    echo $resultado . "<br>Resultado: " . $resultado . 
    "<br>Datos de bienvenida: " . $datosBienvenida;
}
```

I get this:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING - assumed
>   'SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING

And this:

> An invalid PHP type for parameter 3 was specified.

I've been through the following questions and references (and more) and none of them help:

- [PHP Get return value from MSSQL Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25412675/php-get-return-value-from-mssql-stored-procedure?rq=1)
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296183(v=sql.105).aspx

Note: when i try this using WebMatrix i only see the second message.

Comment: `SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING` is nowhere in that code.

Comment: I also tried that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.constants.php):

> SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING (integer)
>   Specifies a string PHP data type. This constant works like a function and accepts an encoding constant.

The constant `SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING` is to be treated as a function as you must pass an encoding constant for it to work. For example:

```
array(&$resultado, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT, SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING(SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR), SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR)
```

Encoding constants and more info on PHPTYPE constants can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296183(v=sql.105).aspx#PHPTYPE-Constants).

---

From above link:

> When you use SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STREAM or SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING, the encoding must be specified. If no parameter is supplied, an error will be returned.

---

**Edit**
As the question title actually asks about `SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR` and not `SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STRING` I should point out that the same is true for the former:

> SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR (integer)
>   Describes the varchar SQL Server data type. This constant works like a function and accepts a single parameter indicating the character count.

So with this you would add a parameter that represents the max character count for that field, just as you would in SQL. So something like:

```
SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR(512)
```

Where `512` is an integer between 1-8000.

For when you use `varchar(MAX)` in SQL you would use:

```
SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARCHAR("max")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution and for the extra reference